# Get hour in UTC timezone and not exchange's timezone in pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

The built-in variable `hour` in pine script refers to the hour in the exchange's timezone. I would like to have a variable called `UTC_hour` to refer to UTC timezone.

I am using pinescript v5.

Comment: Why not use `hour()` built in parameter `timezone`? You can use `hour(time, "UTC")`

Comment: @mr_statler, could you put that down as the answer? I'll mark it as the right answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hour()` function has a `timezone` parameter:

> **timezone (series string)** Allows adjusting the returned value to a time zone specified in either UTC/GMT notation (e.g., "UTC-5", "GMT+0530") or as an IANA time zone database name (e.g., "America/New_York"). Optional. The default is syminfo.timezone.

You can use it like this to get the current bar time in UTC timezone:

```
hour(time, "UTC")
```